# C++ How would I pass a variable through a class with an array index?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am currently modifying a video game and I am having some trouble with the clients. Their are 18 clients in a game. Each client is basically a number. So client 4 = 4 client 16 = 16 etc. So lets say if a client goes into the menu and presses say FlyMode. The ClientIndex number would store the number in the array. Here is my Clients Class.

```
class Client{
public:
    void FlyMode(int Client) { *(int*)(GetEntity(Client) + 0xB4); };
};
```

Instead of having int Client as a parameter, what I want is to pass a variable to indicate the clients number. I want to be able to call FlyMode like this. `Client[ID].FlyMode();` Rather than `Client[ID].FlyMode(ClientID);` I also want to try to avoid havint `Client Clients[18];`

Comment: Use an `unordered_map` with key the ID of the client and value the `Client` object.

Comment: Can you explain more? I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: He means [**one of these**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Look at the methods for examples of how they're used.

Comment: @Warfighter8888 your `Client` is a class. You apply `operator[]` to the class... that can't be right.

Comment: If you don't need 18 separate clients in an array, and your member functions can already modify any client, just rename `Client` to `ClientManager`, just have one of them, and call it a day.  `ClientManager mgr; mgr->FlyMode(ClientID);`

Comment: I need them all in a array. Something like a vector.

Comment: I think you are very confused @Warfighter8888.
`Client[ID]` accesses an array/vector, which i'm going to assume is a static member of the `Client` class (and which frankly they could have named `_allClients` if the initial author wasn't a sadist..). To be able to have your behavior, I suggest changing that `vector` into a map, with the ID as key. Then you can get all the keys as a vector with `_allCleints.keys()`
Also for the love of [insert whatever is holy to you] use the std::lib containers and throw away arrays. Forever. C++. the ++ is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a member data in `Client` that captures a client's ID and use it in `FlyMode`.

```
class Client{
   int ID_;
public:
   Client(int ID) : ID_(ID) {}
   void FlyMode() { *(int*)(GetEntity(this->ID_) + 0xB4); };
};
```

Comment: YEESSS something just like this. I see you understand my question fully. BUT I need it in an array so I can do things like say if we had bool InMenu; in the class, I wouldn't be able to access it unless I had it in an array.

Comment: It's not clear to me what are looking for with the array. Perhaps you can update your post to describe all your questions clearly.

Comment: You're on the spot with it. This is exactly what I need but is it possible to have the clients number stored in an array?

Comment: You don't need to. You can just store an array of `Client`s. If you need the `Client`'s number, add a member function to get the ID, `int getID() { return ID_; }`

Comment: I know but say if I have a boolean in there and I want to modify it outside of the class I would get an error.

Comment: That part is not clear to me. What's the relationship between a boolean value (where do you get it) and a `Client`'s ID?

Comment: Do you have skype or aim? I could explain it alot better on there

Comment: I do but I am not willing to share that info here.

Comment: Ok if you have skype add me

marcus.duhe

Or if you have aim

gamerfreek34@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own collection wrapper over an array and overload operator[] in such a way, that it would tell your objects which id it has. Sth along the lines of this

```
class MyContainer
{
public:
    Client & operator[](int i) { mClients[i].setId(i); return mClients[i]; }
private:
    Client mClients[18];
}
```

Of course you'd probably like to implement it in proper way (range checking?), the code above is just to express an idea.